# Insert / update Deadlock with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-deadlocks

I have a table `A` (`id int, domain nvarchar, status nvarchar`) and a trigger `A_trigger` after insert on table A. The trigger calls a stored procedure and depending on the result of the procedure, updates the status on the newly inserted row.

When I run it in two sessions, I end up with a deadlock issue:

Isolation level: read committed

`INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_TRIGGER (DOMAIN) 
VALUES ('toto')
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.dim_trigger 
ON db.dbo.TEST_TRIGGER
AFTER INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @status nvarchar(200),
            @domain nvarchar(200),
            @trackingId int

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- This code assumes we insert one and only one row at a time.
    SELECT @trackingId = id, @domain = domain FROM INSERTED;

    DECLARE @toCallProcName NVARCHAR(200);
    SET @toCallProcName = 'db.dbo.'+@domain+'_proc';

    EXEC @toCallProcName @status out;

    UPDATE db.dbo.TEST_TRIGGER
    SET status = @status
    WHERE id = @trackingId;
END
```

I tried to:

- issue the update statement with `WITH (UPDLOCK)`, but that's not working
- Creating an index on (ID) works, but I'm concerned about this solution!!

**EDIT1**:

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST_TRIGGER]
(
      [DOMAIN] [NVARCHAR](200) NOT NULL,
      [ID] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [STATUS] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
)
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[toto_proc]
     @res NVARCHAR(200) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:5'
    PRINT 'This is me: '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108) ;
    SET @res = 'OK'
END
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Create an index per row? I don't think you understand what indexes are.

Comment: enlighten me then please :) I'm not a pro

Comment: Show us what you actually did - that index creation per row, because I have no idea what it is you tried to do.

Comment: CREATE INDEX i1_TEST_TRIGGER ON dbo.TEST_TRIGGER (id)

Maybe i should have said "the size of the index will grow up very fast" instead of "..requires to create an index per row." Maybe I do not understand very also

Comment: This is just one index which you create once, not per row. Obviously the size of an index is growing, but "very fast" isn't a number so it's hard to throw an estimate. I wouldn't be concerned about this unless you are inserting thousands rows per second.

Comment: Please include procedure code which your trigger executes and table schema.

Comment: Thx for the explain. I was concerned since this is a tracking table, thus rows will be inserted frequently in a day.
As for the proc code, nothing for now (just a print... still in dev) but will some selects, join, and insert into tables.

Comment: Including a complete MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is helpful to others who would like to help you out, so including your procedure code, even if it's nothing complicated, saves time for others to reproduce your issue.

Comment: ok thx @KamilG.! I'll put that in my mind :)

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code selects from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Thx @marc_s I'm fully aware of that :) Knowing my app I can't have more than two rows inserted per statement. But you are right, I'll improve it later ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for your issue is, Triggers keep holding the lock on the base table. Due to multiple session and same resource this is bound to happen. Having no index on the table will cause table scan every time for each different session and cause deadlock. Applying the index is the right move, because in this way your update statement will hit the granular level. So this should work. I suggest an additional hint of RowLock in your update statement.

### Important : I am assuming, each insert will have only one value to be inserted. Other wise this Trigger has issues. (As mentioned by marc_s)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to create an index on your table

example:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Test_Trigger ON dbo.TEST_TRIGGER(Id)
```

Read this for more info about Index and its impact on locking mechanism:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2517/using-a-clustered-index-to-solve-a-sql-server-deadlock-issue/