# Pentaho Dimension Lookup/Update deadlock error

Tags: etl, pentaho, pdi

I have a Dimension Lookup/update step, and I am trying to update a table with data from JSON files, but it is failing with the following error:

```
2021/08/03 12:51:58 - dlu-insrting_in_table.0 - ERROR (version 9.1.0.0-324, build 9.1.0.0-324 from 2020-09-07 05.09.05 by buildguy) : Because of an error this step can't continue: 
2021/08/03 12:51:58 - dlu-insrting_in_table.0 - Couldn't get row from result set
2021/08/03 12:51:58 - dlu-insrting_in_table.0 - Transaction (Process ID 78) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

This is the configuration of the Dimension Lookup/update step.
[image]

and this is part of the transformation

[image]

If I use only one copy to start the step, it works everything ok, but if I put more than one it gives me the mentioned error. The thing is that the error seems to be casual, sometime crashes after inserting two rows, other times it inserts everything without giving the error.

Searching the documentation and in interned didn't help much, I was not able to fix it. I read that could be a insertion order problem or a primary key related problem, but the data is fine (the keys are unique) and the configuration of the step seems ok. What I noticed is that does not insert the Technical key in order, I think is because it depends on the process that finishes first, but I don't find a way to force it (assuming this is the problem).

Does anyone know which is the problem here, and how could I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t run multiple copies of the Lookup/Update step. It has a commit size of 100, so if you have 2 copies of the step you have two threads concurrently trying to update the same table. Most likely one of them is locking the table ( or a block of rows) that the other tries to write and that lock causes a timeout.

Why it sometimes crashes and sometimes works? It’s actually a bit random: each copy receives a batch of rows to act upon, and it depends on which rows are sent to each copy and how many updates are required.

Comment: I manage to solve the problem, it was an index problem. Yes, you can run multiple copies on Lookup/Update also by using a commit size of 100. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve the problem finally. The problem was not related with Pentaho strictly but with SQL Server. In particular, I had to redefine the index on the table on which the insertion was made. You will find more details in this answer: [Insert/Update deadlock with SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51723002/insert-update-deadlock-with-sql-server)